# Me gustaria mostrar una el nombre del usuario que esta autenticado actualmente en mi plantilla

Tags: python, django

Buenos dias programadores, en este dia me encontre con un problema al cual no le he podido encontrar solucion, me gustaria mostrar el nombre y el apellido del usuario que actualmente ha ingresado, tengo una relacion foreignkey hacia el modelo de User de django para la creacion de usuarios, me gustaria mostrar esa relacion de reversa al modelo que esta relacion a USER en mi plantilla.

## Esta es mi plantilla, en esa etiqueta 'p' es en donde me gustaria mostrar el usuario

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load staticfiles%}
{%block body_block%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'index/css/index.css'%}">
{%if user.is_authenticated%}
    <p>Hello {{user.userregister.nombre}}</p>
{%endif%}
        <nav>
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class="clear">
                    <li><a href="{% url 'patients' %}" title="home"><i class="fas fa-users"></i><span class="link-text">Pacientes</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="{% url 'appointmentindex'%}" title="about"><i class="far fa-calendar-check"></i></i><span class="link-text">Consultas</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="pricing"><i class="fa fa-money-bill-alt"></i><span class="link-text">Registros</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="services"><i class="fa fa-tools"></i><span class="link-text">Proveedores</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span class="link-text">Configuracion</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="" title="services"><i class="fa fa-tools"></i><span class="link-text">Ayuda</span></a></li>
                    {%if user.is_authenticated%}
                    <li><a href="" title="contact"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><span class="link-text">Cerrar Sesion</span></a></li>
                    {%endif%}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

{%endblock%}
```

## Estos son mis modelos

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class UserRegister(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Nombre = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='', blank=False)
    Apellido = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='', blank=False)
    Correo_Electronico = models.EmailField(unique=True, blank=False,default='')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que tienes una relación **uno a muchos**, es decir:

> Un `UserRegister` no puede tener más de un `User` **pero un `User`
>   puede tener varios `UserRegister`** o "registros de usuario" (o algo
>   así)...

Eso quiere decir que un usuario va a tener varios "registros de usuario", lo cual según tus intenciones no es lo que quieres, la relación **debería ser uno a uno**, no uno a varios.

En todo caso, de todas maneras lo quieras hacer así, primero quiero explicarte algo, como te dije anteriormente un usuario puede tener varios "registros de usuario", es decir que estamos hablando de **varias instancias relacionadas**, y para acceder a ellas, es de la siguiente manera (esto se conoce como "relacion inversa", para mas detalles, revisa la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)):

```
>>> user.userregister_set.all()
<QuerySet: [...]> # Varias instancias del modelo "UserRegister"
>>> user.userregister.all()[0]
<UserRegister: ...> # Primera instancia relacionada
```

Y para hacer lo que intentabas hacer en tu template, seria así:

```
{{ user.userregister_set.all.0.nombre }}
```

Recuerda que son varias instancias relacionadas, así que estamos accediendo a la primera instancia (eso lo indicamos con el indice 0), y toma en cuenta que pueden haber mas.

Esto solucionaría tu problema, pero lo que yo te recomiendo, es una relación uno a uno:

```
class UserRegister(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

De esta manera, seria la forma correcta e incluso seria mas simple acceder a la instancia relacionada:

```
>>> user.userregister
<UserRegister: ...>
>>> user.userregister.nombre
...
```

Y en tu template, **si funcionaria como lo estas haciendo**:

```
{{ user.userregister.nombre }}
```

---

Eso seria todo, pero en mi opinión, todo esto de crear el modelo, relacionarlo, etc. **Es totalmente innecesario, por que todos los campos del modelo `UserRegister`, los tiene el mismo modelo `User`, por defecto de Django.** Asi que estas repitiendo código de cierta manera o reinventando la rueda.

Te recomiendo revisar la [documentación de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/auth/#fields), sobre los campos del modelo `User`, por defecto de Django.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Vaya que si me ayudo mucho, ya hice el cambio a mis tablas e hice la relacion OnetoOne y si funciono a la perfeccion @Julio Cesar, fijate que intente hacer lo mismo en otra vista pero no me permitio mostrarlo, pero esta vista es renderizada a un pdf, no se si sera por eso, hice el mismo procedimiento y los procesos que quiero que se cumplan al momento de evaluar la expresion {{if user.is_authenticated}} no me muestra nada en el pdf, no se si sera un comportamiento por default del pdf o no se si estare haciendo algo mal, tu que opinas jaja? y de nuevo muchisimas gracias, si me sirvio de mucho!

Comment: Pues la verdad no se mucho de PDF's en Django, según tenia entendido esto del "contexto", variables de "contexto", el lenguaje de plantillas, etc. **Solo es para los templates**. no para PDF's... por cierto un gusto ayudarte! :)